# Veracrypt hash algorithm detection

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to detect the hash algorithm used to encrypt a file or partition with Veracrypt?

Comment: mount the volume then from `Volumes` menu select `volume properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you know the correct password. VeraCrypt works by trying each hash and cipher combination with your supplied password one-at-a-time until one of them works, and tells you that your password is incorrect if none work. Without the correct password, you can't even tell if it's a VeraCrypt volume or not.

Comment: Interestingly, a wrong password took around 30 seconds to return incorrect information. The correct one around 3 sec. I think this is more than testing all available combinations!

Comment: @kelalaka no. You probably just use the default settings and VeraCrypt tries them first.

Comment: If you are talking about PKCS5-PRF, it is on auto detection.